# select monthly report where per day transction show in single row

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
   Date -               Amount 
12-nov-2016              200
12-nov-2016              100
13- nov -2016            400
13 -nov-2016             200
```

result show like-

```
Date                     Amount 
12- nov-2016             300
13- nov-2016             600
```

as whole month

Answer (score 1):

```
select [Date], sum(Amount) as Amount from yourTable group by [Date]
```

Comment: Amount** dude, not Ammount :)

Comment: its show all result single date ,i need only total amount sum per day datewise

Comment: its show like -                                                                                                      Date                 Amount
2016-05-02  4100
2016-05-02  750                                                                                   i need     date -    2016-05-02 02    amount- 4850

Comment: you have text field as date in your table?